# strings - get characters before a digit

Tags: go

I have some strings such `E2 9NZ`,  `N29DZ`, `EW29DZ` . I need to extract the chars  before the first digit, given the above example :  `E`, `N`, `EW`.
Am I supposed to use regex ? The [strings](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package looks really nice but just doesn't seem to handle this case (extract everything before a specific type).

**Edit:**

To clarify the "question" I'm wondering what method is more idiomatic to [go](http://golang.org/) and perhaps likely to provide better performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func DigitPrefix(s string) string {
    for i, r := range s {
        if unicode.IsDigit(r) {
            return s[:i]
        }
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(DigitPrefix("E2 9NZ"))
    fmt.Println(DigitPrefix("N29DZ"))
    fmt.Println(DigitPrefix("EW29DZ"))
    fmt.Println(DigitPrefix("WXYZ"))
}
```

Output:

```
E
N
EW
WXYZ
```

If there is no digit, example `"WXYZ"`, and you don't want anything returned, change `return s` to `return ""`.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need regex for this problem. You can easily walk through on a slice of rune and check the current character with unicode.IsDigit(), if it's a digit: return. If it isn't: continue the loop. If there are no numbers: return the argument

### Code

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"unicode"
)

func UntilDigit(r []rune) []rune {
   var i int
   for _, v := range r {
    if unicode.IsDigit(v) {
        return r[0:i]
    }
    i++
   }
   return r
}

func main() {
fmt.Println(string(UntilDigit([]rune("E2 9NZ"))))
fmt.Println(string(UntilDigit([]rune("N29DZ"))))
fmt.Println(string(UntilDigit([]rune("EW29DZ"))))
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/6d5vJxQZNF)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why almost everyone provided answers in everything but Go. Here is regex-based Go version:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    pattern, err := regexp.Compile("^[^\\d]*")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    part := pattern.Find([]byte("EW29DZ"))
    if part != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Found: %s\n", string(part))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not found")
    }
}
```

Running:

```
% go run main.go 
Found: EW
```

[Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IFn8f41-Sg)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use the index returned from `strings.IndexAny` which will return the first index of any character in a string.

```
func BeforeNumbers(str string) string { 
    value := strings.IndexAny(str,"0123456789")
    if value >= 0 && value <= len(str) {
        return str[:value]
    }

    return str
}
```

Will slice the string and return the subslice up to (but not including) the first character that's in the string `"0123456789"` which is any number.

Way later edit:

It would probably be better to use IndexFunc rather than IndexAny:

```
func BeforeNumbers(str string) string { 
    indexFunc := func(r rune) bool {
       return r >= '0' && r <= '9'
    }
    value := strings.IndexFunc(str,indexFunc)
    if value >= 0 && value <= len(str) {
        return str[:value]
    }

    return str
}
```

This is more or less equivalent to the loop version, and eliminates a search over a long string to check for a match every character from my previous answer. But I think it looks cleaner than the loop version, which is obviously a manner of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will continue grabbing characters until it reaches a digit.

```
int i = 0;
String string2test = "EW29DZ";
String stringOutput = "";

while (!Character.isDigit(string2test.charAt(i))) 
   {
   stringOutput = stringOutput + string2test.charAt(i);
   i++;
   }
```

Comment: I think it's not actually go . The type is supposed to be declared after, isn't it ?

Comment: It's not Go code. He didn't say that initially, and I missed the tag.

Comment: @codemonkey That's not true!  "Go" was specified initially, just that there was no href. Also "go" has been the only tag assigned to the question.

Comment: I said I missed the tag.  It's my fault.